# Flutter/Dart: RichText and TextField removes beginning spaces at display

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a RichText Widget in Flutter where I want to print the attribute `LUKETXT` which is in a Modell.
The problem is, that `LUKETXT` is containing whitespaces at the beginning, like for example:

```
'                                                                                          *end of invoice*                                          '
```

But when I want to display it, the whitespaces at the beginning where removed.

My function is:

```
RichText BuildText(List<OrderReceipt> OrderReceipt) {
  int deflen = OrderReceipt.length;
  return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "PolarSys",fontSize: 10),
      spellOut: false,
      children: [
        for (int i =0; i<deflen; i++)
            TextSpan(
              spellOut: false,
              text: OrderReceipt[i].LUKETXT,
            )
      ]
    ),
  );
}
```

Just for information: PolarSys Font is a Monospace Font, that's the reason I gonna build it like that.

Does anyone know what is wrong? I already experimentet with `spellOut` `true` and `false` but there was no change.

Thanks..

Comment: As a matter of interest, are you creating the receipt to print it? If so there may be better ways to create it than using rich text eg. https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Comment: @GrahamD: I want to sign the receipt at the end, so I need to show it and then with a `Stack` I position the sign field on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely with the leading whitespaces being removed by the TextSpan widget. In Flutter, the TextSpan widget is designed to remove leading whitespaces by default. To preserve the leading whitespaces, you can use a Text widget instead of TextSpan. You can wrap the Text widget inside a parent widget like a Padding or a SizedBox to add the necessary whitespaces before the text.

Comment: Thank you, I made some `Text()` widgets in a `Column()`